# LookupError: unknown encoding 'big5' under embeded python

Tags: python, c, r

I am building a R extension which has an embedded python in it.

Everything goes well now, except that the python cannot find the encoding I needed. It keeps throwing LookupError when I do something involving 'big5'. However, if I build a stand alone c++ application, the python interpreter does find the encoding and stop throwing errors.

`test.cpp` for normal stand alone example in c:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Py_SetProgramName("test");  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString(
            "import codecs\n"
            "f = codecs.open('big5_encoded_file', encoding='big5', mode='r')"
            );
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

`testr.cpp` for R extension:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <Python.h>

extern "C" SEXP testpy();

SEXP testpy() {
  Py_SetProgramName("test");  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString(
            "import codecs\n"
            "f = codecs.open('big5_encoded_file', encoding='big5', mode='r')"
            );
    Py_Finalize();
    return R_NilValue;
}
```

A `Makefile` on ubuntu 12.10:

```
all: test testr.so

test: test.cpp
  g++ test.cpp -o test -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7


testr.so: testr.cpp
    R CMD SHLIB testr.cpp
```

The `./test` runs normally, but `Rscript -e "dyn.load('testr.so');.Call('testpy')"` produces a "LookupError: unknown encoding: big5"

Thanks

-- edit --

To build the `testr.so`, please set:

```
export PKG_CXXFLAGS=-I/usr/include/python2.7
export PKG_LIBS=-lpython2.7
```

Comment: Seems like R does not fully support the Big5 character encoding, perhaps? Or that a different module/Python version is being loaded in the `.so` version? Also, you may want to clarify what your question is. Presumably it is "why can't this embedded Python load a Big5-encoded file?"

Comment: You're using the names `C` and `C++` interchangeably, they're not the same thing.

Comment: @PhilipHanson, As far as I know, R does support Big5. Maybe the embedded python interpreter is different. Could you tell me how to detect some system settings in python? 

My question is about the "LookupError", which is the reason why the embedded python cannot load a Big5-encoded file according to the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that it is a linking issue.

I tried to `import encodings.big5` in the embedded python, but the error of `undefined reference` occurred. The solution in http://bugs.python.org/issue4434 works for me:

> before `PyInitialize()` I can call `dlopen("libpython2.7.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);`